# Is there a way to limit css classes for a html element?

Tags: css, class

I know you can add them to a class, seemingly endlessly but is there a way to prevent certain classes to an element or define only which classes can be added?

Comment: No.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @SLaks I think he's trying to ask if there's a way to have styles for only a certain group of elements within a certain tag, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: Limiting style to a single element can be done by styling on ID's, but that is rarely a good idea.

Comment: What I'd like to know is if I can limit which classes an elements class can be changed to, so it can be changed to say class A and B but not to class C

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with jquery, if it is really important.
Look at these two functions:

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("element").addclass("myclass");
    $("element2").click(function(){
        $("element").removeclass("myclass");
    });
});
```

With this you could prevent, that the class "badclass" is added to the div element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").removeclass("badclass");
});
```

To remove all classes you could remove the class attribute from your object, but not sure if it's gonna work.

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Here you remove all classes from the div elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").removeattr("class");
});
```

Greets and i hope it helps a little bit